# Как работают динамические теги JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

Искал, как сделать заголовки компонента зависимыми от props и наткнулся на такой пример:

```
const Title = ({priority})=> {
   const CustomTag = `h${priority}`;

   return (<CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>)
}
```

Я так понял, что там создаётся как бы компонента `CustomTag` но в неё записывается строка, хотя в React как я понимаю компонент должен быть классом или функцией, но почему тогда это работает?

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как это работает?**

Comment: Конкретно это работает только для priority от 1 до 6. Т.к. создаётся тобычный html тег h1/.../h6.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я понимаю к каким резльтатам это приводит. Я не совсем понимаю, почему это работает ведь CustomTag тэг это вроде не компонента, а просто текст....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel не проверяет, что такое `CustomTag`. Ему важно только с большой или маленькой буквы начинается имя. JSX это просто синтаксический сахар и в конечном итоге он превращается в `React.createElement`. Вся разница только в том, что если переменная начинается с большой буквы, то она не будет взята в кавычки.

Например `<span>test</span>` превратится в `React.createElement('span', …)`, а `<Span>test</Span>` в `React.createElement(Span, …)`.

При этом `React.createElement` сам проверяет тип первого аргумента и если это строка, то он создаёт обычный DOM-элемент, а если функция/класс, то пользовательский компонент.

В вашем примере будет вызван примерно такой код:

```js
React.createElement(
    `h${priority}`,
    null,
    'Hello'
);
```

А дальше `React.createElement` разберётся что ему передали строку и создаст соответствующий элемент.